# What must I do for visual studio 2017 to use the natstepfilter file to avoid stepping into std library functions and class methods?

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2017

First, I am testing this capability by editing the default.natstepfilter file on purpose.  I realize that there is a just my code feature built into visual studio now and an associated compiler setting /JMC.  However I have a legacy project that is built using the older VS2013 tools still so I can't use the newer just my code feature to avoid stepping into STL and other library functions.  Therefore I have setup a simple hello world example to figure out how to use the technique described in these next two articles.

Having read these two articles, the filters are slightly different. I have tried both ways with and without escaping the colon character but neither seems to work.
https://blog.wholetomato.com/2020/08/18/prevent-debugger-from-stepping-into-unwanted-functions-in-visual-studio/
https://www.asawicki.info/news_1486_how_to_make_visual_studio_debugger_not_step_into_stl.html

Consider this code. When stepping into printGreeting that takes the c-string I do not want to step into c_str() method of std::string, but I have to click f-11 to step into printGreeting so this is my test case for verifying that the change to default.natstepfilter works.

I've tried these two lines recommended by the aforementioned sites but neither seems to have an effect.  I don't think the escape of the colon is needed but that is how one example showed it.

```
<Function><Name>std::.+ </Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action>
<Function><Name>std\:\:.* </Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action>
```

Here is the sample code.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printGreeting(const char* greeting) {
    std::cout << greeting << std::endl; 
}

int main()
{
   std::string greeting("Hello World!\n");
   printGreeting(greeting.c_str());
}
```

I have also tried restarting visual studio 2017 after editing the .natstepfilter which had no effect.  The debugger still steps into the constructor of std::string and the c_str() method.

Comment: I _think_ you want `<Function><Name>std::.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>`. Also, you'd generally need to restart VS for changes to take effect.

Comment: I appreciate that.  I tried that variant of the entry in the xml file and ensured that visual studio was restarted.  I also rebooted the PC just in case there was something holding onto a VS process and that still didn't result in the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved my own issue by starting over and creating a new file with the .natstepfilter extension.  I can't prove that a mistake in the file was the problem because the previous files I tried were changed or deleted already.  However I am fairly confident that there was an error in my edited .natstepfilter file.  I was able to reproduce the problem again by purposefully inserting an error.  In my original post my xml sample entries were wrong.  It was missing the trailing tag .  It's possible when I copy and pasted examples from a browser window that I didn't copy the entire line or that I copied something extra. It's also possible that I didn't copy and paste correctly from my edited file into the original question. **When the file contains an error, it will silently fail to be loaded.  I couldn't find a diagnostic output anywhere that showed the problem loading that file.**

I also learned from the Microsoft documentation that you can create a new .natstepfilter file with any name that you like instead of modifying the default so prefer that approach to avoid introducing an error into the original. Here is the content of the file I created which did work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">
  <Function><Name>std::.*</Name><Action>NoStepInto</Action></Function>
</StepFilter>
```

Moreover you can put these files in your %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Visualizers directory so that you do not have to add a file to a system installation directory. I did have to manually create the Visualizers directory and then create the file.  You can add multiple files with the extension if you'd like to organize the entries across multiple files.